# Show that ${n \choose k}\leq n^k$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, induction, binomial-coefficients

> Let $n$ et $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that : $k\leq n $
>
> Show that :$${n \choose k}\leq n^{k}$$

***My thoughts:***

note that  for all $\ k\leq n$ :

$${n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

To prove that the following statement, which we will call $P(n)$, holds for all natural numbers n:$${n \choose k}\leq n^{k}$$

so my proof that P(n) is true for each natural number n proceeds as follows:

**Basis:** Show that the statement holds for $n=0$.

P($0$) amounts to the statement:
$${0 \choose 0}=\frac{0!}{0!(0-0)!}\leq 0^{0},\quad (k\leq 0 \implies k=0)$$
$$0\leq 0 $$
the statement is true for $n=0$. Thus it has been shown that P($0$) holds.

**Inductive step:** Show that if P($k$) holds, then also P(${k+1}$) holds. This can be done as follows.

Assume P($n$) holds. It must then be shown that P($n+1$) holds, that is:
$${{n+1} \choose k}\leq {(n+1)}^{k}$$

note that $$\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \frac{(n+1)}{(k+1)}\binom n k$$

$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \frac{(n+1)}{(k)}\binom n {k-1}$$

Using the induction hypothesis that P($n$) holds, the last expression can be rewritten to:
$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \frac{(n+1)}{(k)}\binom n {k-1}\leq  \frac{(n+1)}{(k)}{(n)}^{k-1}$$

i'm stuch here thereby i can't showing that indeed P($n+1$) holds.

- Am i right and is there others ways to prove it

**Edit:**

**Basis:** Show that the statement holds for $n=0$.

P($0$) amounts to the statement:
$${0 \choose 0}=\frac{0!}{0!(0-0)!}\leq 0^{0},\quad (k\leq 0 \implies k=0)$$
$$0\leq 0 $$
the statement is true for $n=0$. Thus it has been shown that P($0$) holds.

**Inductive step:** Show that if P($k$) holds, then also P(${k+1}$) holds. This can be done as follows.

Assume P($n$) holds. It must then be shown that P($n+1$) holds, that is:
$${{n+1} \choose k}\leq {(n+1)}^{k}$$

note that  $\displaystyle{n+1 \choose k}={n \choose k-1}+{n \choose k}$
Using the induction hypothesis that P($n$) holds, the last expression can be rewritten to:

$$\displaystyle{n+1 \choose k}\le n^{k-1}+n^k=(1+n)n^{k-1} \le (n+1)^k$$ though for completeness you might add that $${n+1 \choose 0}=1\le (n+1)^0$$ and $${n+1 \choose n+1}=1\le (n+1)^{n+1}$$.

because the main part does not quite work for $$\displaystyle {n+1 \choose 0}={n \choose -1}+{n \choose 0}$$ or for $$\displaystyle{n+1 \choose n+1}={n \choose n}+{n \choose n+1}$$

the inductive hypothesis does not cover either $\displaystyle{n \choose -1}$ or $\displaystyle{n \choose n+1}.$

Is my reasoning correct

Comment: $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so basis must be shown for $n = 1$, not $0$.

Comment: I wonder how hard it would be to turn the idea of "both sides are the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $n$, but the right hand side keeps track of order" into a proof. To be honest, I've accepted reasoning like this when teaching combinatorics but standards vary. Maybe write, with $J = \{1, \dots, n\}$, the obvious map $J^n \to (\text{subsets of $J$ of size $k$})$, argue that it's surjective. Of course, then one ought to justify that the two sides have the right orders, that a surjection between finite sets induces an inequality...

Answer (score 7):

Another idea:
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-k+1)}{k!} \leq n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-k+1) \leq n^k.
$$

Comment: but you didn't told me if i am right or nope or even we can prove it by induction

Answer (score 4):

$n \choose k$ counts the number of subsets of size $k$ from a set of $n$ elements. $n^k$ counts the number of ordered strings of length $k$ from a set of $n$ elements. Clearly, there are more ordered strings of length $k$ than there are unordered subsets of the size $k$, and thus the inequality holds.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown by induction.

From [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) you have $\displaystyle{n+1 \choose k}={n \choose k-1}+{n \choose k}$ and so applying your inductive hypothesis $$\displaystyle{n+1 \choose k}\le n^{k-1}+n^k=(1+n)n^{k-1} \le (n+1)^k$$ though for completeness you might add that ${n+1 \choose 0}=1\le (n+1)^0$ and ${n+1 \choose n+1}=1\le (n+1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: is my statement holds for $n=0$.

Comment: By convention in combinatorics $0^0=1$ to make the binomial expansion work, so I do not see a problem with your initial step.

Comment: so i have just to add what you wrote and my prove will be okay

Comment: My answer was designed to replace your inductive step

Comment: but i can't see why we ve to add that : ${n+1 \choose 0}=1\le (n+1)^0$ and ${n+1 \choose n+1}=1\le (n+1)^{n+1}$. i think $\displaystyle{n+1 \choose k}\le (n+1)^k$ holds for $k\leq n$ am i right ?

Comment: The main part does not quite work for $\displaystyle {n+1 \choose 0}={n \choose -1}+{n \choose 0}$ or for $\displaystyle{n+1 \choose n+1}={n \choose n}+{n \choose n+1}$ as the inductive hypothesis does not cover either $\displaystyle{n \choose -1}$ or $\displaystyle{n \choose n+1}$.

Comment: please see my update