# How to show that $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \implies 1\leq \left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n}\leq \epsilon$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

> Show that
>
> $\forall n\geq 1,\quad  \forall \epsilon > 0,\forall x \in \mathbb{R},$
>
> $$0 \leq x \leq \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \implies 1\leq \left(1+\frac{x}{n}  \right)^{n}\leq \epsilon$$

This question is related to that one [Let $n\geq 1$ and $\alpha \in [0,1)$ show that : $1\le \bigl(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\bigr)^{n}\le \frac{1}{1-\alpha}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090892/1-le-bigl1-frac-alphan-bigrn-le-frac11-alpha)

**My thoughts:**

Since $0 \leq x \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}< 1$ (because of $\epsilon < \epsilon+1 \quad \forall \epsilon > 1 $) then by that question [Let $n\geq 1$ and $\alpha \in [0,1)$ show that : $1\le \bigl(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\bigr)^{n}\le \frac{1}{1-\alpha}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090892/1-le-bigl1-frac-alphan-bigrn-le-frac11-alpha) we've :

$$1\le \left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^{n}\le \dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

Still we've to prove that :

$$\dfrac{1}{1-x}\le 1+\epsilon$$

Or we have $0 \leq x \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \implies 1-\dfrac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \leq 1-x \leq 1 \implies \dfrac{1}{1+\epsilon} \leq 1-x \leq 1 $ which prove that last inequality

- Is my reasoning correct or is there another ways to prove that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct, assuming the RHS is $1+\varepsilon$. Another way would be to observe that $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ increases when you increase $x$, so you only have to prove it for $x=\varepsilon/(1+\varepsilon):$
$$\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon/(1+\varepsilon)}n\right)\le\frac1{1-\varepsilon/(1+\varepsilon)}=\frac{1+\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon-\varepsilon}=1+\varepsilon$$

Comment: i answered it correctly and there is no upvote

Comment: @Educ What did you expect? Your question is quite trivial and uninteresting given the previous question.